# Why does this wiringPi serial code break my Arduino sketch?

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have a simple Arduino sketch below.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
}
```

When using my computer *or* Picocom (a serial utility for the Raspberry Pi), the Arduino's status LED (tied to pin 13) is constantly on, except the quick flash when resetting the Arduino.

I want to try to connect this to a Raspberry Pi. (Please note that it is using the USB connection, **not the built in UART pin on the GPIO header.**) I'm currently using the *wiringPi* library with this code.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <string>

int serialDeviceId = 0;

int main() {
  serialDeviceId = serialOpen("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600);
  wiringPiSetup();
  for(;;) {
    serialPrintf(serialDeviceId, "%c", '0');
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

However, for some reason, the status LED on the Arduino is off when this code is run until I hit the *reset* button. 30% of the time when that happens the LED toggles the state (on --> off, and vice versa). Sometimes it randomly shuts off. There's no predictable pattern. I haven't been able to see someone with a similar online. It might be that the code makes it reset rapidly, but the light goes HIGH when it reset, not LOW, so that doesn't make much sense.